# Summing of numbers in jquery returning NAN

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to sum values from an input array but the sum it keeps returning NAN

```
var sum = 0    //i have also tried parse(0,10);
$(qty_name).each(function(){
    var aValue = $(this).val(); //i have tried parseInt($(this).val(), 10)
    sum += aValue; //i have tried sum = parseInt(sum) + parseInt(aValue)
});
alert(sum);
```

i keep getting NaN. I'm coming from a php background so i've never had to deal with type casting. Please what am i missing?

Comment: Can you show `qty_name`

Comment: Can you add the rest of the script and html?

Comment: `var aValue += $(this).val()`: initial value of `aValue` will be undefined, so incrementing will not do anything useful.

Comment: did you initialize `aValue`?

Comment: @Richard and andrew sorry that's a mistake. 
anton & teedejee the qty_name is a variable containing the particular input element i'm getting. it's passing fine, its just the type casting and the summing i'm having issue with

Comment: @ObiIk Can you show the input elements it is holding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because your other qty_name do not have perfect integer value. which results to NAN for such values. You need to parse the values to int(or float) for doing any mathematical calucations:

```
 var sum = 0;
 $(qty_name).each(function(){
   sum += parseInt($(this).val()) || 0;
 });
 alert(sum);
```

Comment: hey please can you explain that to me

Comment: as i have already mentioned, parseInt fails to convert the values which are not perfect integer which results in NAN. what or operator does here is it use value 0 when result of parsing is NAN.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this:

```
var sum = 0;
$(qty_name).each(function(){
    sum += +($(this).value()); //+ converts to a number
});
alert(sum);
```

---

You were doing wrong with `var aValue += $(this).val()` where you're defining the variable you should not use `+=` operator. You should have done like this:

```
var sum = 0    //i have also tried parse(0,10);
$(qty_name).each(function(){
    var aValue = $(this).val(); //removed + sign before = sign
    sum += aValue; //i have tried sum = parseInt(sum) + parseInt(aValue)
});
alert(sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `parseInt` or `parseFloat`, but here you are using `var aValue += $(this).val();` and aValue is not initialised. Directly add value to `sum`

```
var sum = 0;
$(qty_name).each(function(){
    sum += parseInt($(this).val(), 10)||0;
});
alert(sum);
```

Comment: he says he tried parseInt in the comments of the code you quoted. :). Actually its a better practice to use the second parameter which ensurs conversion to decimal. like parseInt(val,10).

Comment: @mithunsatheesh, yeah I agree with you that using `parseInt(val,10)` is better practice

Answer (score 0):

Try using `isNaN` and `parseInt` as shown :

```
var sum = 0;
$(qty_name).each(function(){
  sum += (isNaN($(this).val()) ? 0 : parseInt($(this).val(),10)); 
});
alert(sum)
```

Comment: @ObiIk..not possible...used isNaN() for this purpose

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understand from your question, you try to avoid adding NaN, use the jQuery built-in method `.isNumeric()` for that like (and of course `+=` on `undefined` doesn't end well):

```
var sum = 0;
$(qty_name).each(function(){
    var aValue = parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
    if(!$.isNumeric(aValue)) return;
    sum += aValue;
});
alert(sum);
```