# Total sum is NaN - Javascript

Tags: javascript

Hello this is what i want to do. Everytime when the table change it will sum the total grade. But the problem is when im trying to sum it the total is NaN. Can someone help me about this?

HERE IS MY CODE.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href ="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="img/png" href="img/gapclogo.png"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
    .table-bordered{
        width: auto !important;
        margin-top: 200px;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>


    <table class="table table-bordered" align="center" >

        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th width="300">Name</th>
                <th width="100">Long Quiz 20%</th>
                <th width="100">Attendance 10%</th>
                <th width="100">Homework/Seatwork 20%</th>
                <th width="100">Recitation 10%</th>
                <th width="100">Major Exam 40%</th>
                <th width="100">Grade</th>
                <th width="100">Equivalent</th>
                 <th width="100">Remarks</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td contenteditable="true" onkeydown="Calculate();" id="quiz"></td>
                <td contenteditable="true" onkeydown="Calculate();" id="atten"></td>
                <td contenteditable="true" onkeydown="Calculate();" id="home"></td>
                <td contenteditable="true" onkeydown="Calculate();" id="reci"></td>
                <td contenteditable="true" onkeydown="Calculate();" id="me"></td>
                <td id="td_grade"></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>


    <script src="js/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
            function Calculate()
        {
            var q = parseInt(document.getElementById('quiz').value);
            var a = parseInt(document.getElementById('atten').value);
            var h = parseInt(document.getElementById('home').value);
            var r = parseInt(document.getElementById('reci').value);
            var m = parseInt(document.getElementById('me').value);

         var grade = q + a + h + r + m;

         document.getElementById('td_grade').innerHTML = grade;      
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just debug it... you'll probably find with 1 minute of work that each `document.getElementById('...').value` is null, or that `parseInt()` of that is `NaN`.

Comment: `parseInt("")` is `NaN`, So `NaN` + anyValue will be `NaN`

Comment: is one of the values empty or not an integer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Summing of numbers in jquery returning NAN](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25787151/summing-of-numbers-in-jquery-returning-nan)

Comment: Then how can i add it sir?

Comment: How do you add them? You're adding them correctly already. Just parse it correctly.

Comment: When you say quiz.value what are you expecting to get back? It's just an empty td...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use [`Unary plus(+)` or `Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_()) instead of `parseInt` as `parseInt('')` will be evaluated as `NaN`
- Use `textContent` instead of `value`
- Note: Use [`onInput`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) instead of `onkeydown`

```js
function Calculate() {
  var q = +(document.getElementById('quiz').textContent);
  var a = +(document.getElementById('atten').textContent);
  var h = +(document.getElementById('home').textContent);
  var r = +(document.getElementById('reci').textContent);
  var m = +(document.getElementById('me').textContent);

  var grade = q + a + h + r + m;

  document.getElementById('td_grade').innerHTML = grade;
}
```

```css
.table-bordered {
  width: auto !important;
  margin-top: 200px;
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-bordered" align="center">

  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th width="300">Name</th>
      <th width="100">Long Quiz 20%</th>
      <th width="100">Attendance 10%</th>
      <th width="100">Homework/Seatwork 20%</th>
      <th width="100">Recitation 10%</th>
      <th width="100">Major Exam 40%</th>
      <th width="100">Grade</th>
      <th width="100">Equivalent</th>
      <th width="100">Remarks</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td contenteditable="true" oninput="Calculate();" id="quiz"></td>
      <td contenteditable="true" oninput="Calculate();" id="atten"></td>
      <td contenteditable="true" oninput="Calculate();" id="home"></td>
      <td contenteditable="true" oninput="Calculate();" id="reci"></td>
      <td contenteditable="true" oninput="Calculate();" id="me"></td>
      <td id="td_grade"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I put 10 in quiz, attendance, homework, recitation, major exam the answer should be 50 but the result is 41 lol